# Is it possible to have a new line in Discord be transferred over to a new line in Google Sheets?

Tags: python, google-sheets, discord

I'm working on a discord/google sheets bot in python.  I have the bot set up connect the two.  I was wondering if it was possible to have a new line in a discord message be copied to a new cell.  The entire message would make up the row.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason why this wouldn't be possible, I've done the same with Node.js.

Here is a link to the Google Sheets quickstart guide for Python:
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python

From my experience using this with Node, it can be slightly tedious. However, once you get it working, copying the actual Discord message to a new row shouldn't be too difficult.

You can get the message content with something like:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message():
    msg = message.content
...
```

Then, integrate it with the guide below:
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values#writing_to_a_single_range